# transmission-gtk before login

Tags: 14.04, gtk, transmission

I know, probably Im asking too much, but...
is there any chance to run transmission-gtk even if any user is logged in?

I should have transmission-daemon installed instead of gtk, but I love GUI..

Comment: try http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login